# Issue with SSH key on Bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have a Bitbucket account and I used my `SSH key` as the `deployment key` by accident and now when I try to enter my SSH key I get the infamous `Someone has already registered this as a deploy key`. I'm the only person using this account, no one else.

Also, if I `git push -u origin --all` I get:

```
conq: repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

When the `deployment key` was deleted already. I even deleted my account and created a new one and still getting `Someone has already registered this as a deploy key`.

I'm trying to push from Cloud9 to Bitbucket so I don't know if creating a new SSH key is an option.

I don't know what else to do and neither the guys at Bitbucket. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Take the Easy Path

The deployment key is obviously attached to some BitBucket team or repository *somewhere*, so unless you can track it down the easiest thing to do is just create a new keypair. This is easy enough to do, and will save you much pain and suffering.

Making a new key takes moments. Ensuring that you distribute your new key takes a bit longer, but still may be less trouble than tracking down a public key that's escaped into the wild. Upload your new public key to BitBucket as an account key, not as a deployment key. Then use /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id from the openssh-client package to quickly distribute the new key to your various internal servers, if you like.

Your problem could be resolved within minutes if you take the easy path. I heartily recommend it.

Comment: Hi, as I said before my project is https://c9.io/ and I'm not really sure if you can create a key. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing commit and push without `git init`. That's why it kept telling Someone has already registered that SSH key.

Answer (score 0):

> ## Resolution
>
> Open a terminal with SSH configured for Bitbucket Cloud and enter the
> following
>
> ```
> ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
> ```

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/someone-has-already-registered-that-ssh-key-338365482.html